# How to get python3.10 in ubuntu 18.04 container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.10

I am looking for some help in writing docker file which eventually creates an Ubuntu 18.04 container with Python 3.10 executable.

Is there any way that I can get the Python3.10 with Ubuntu 18.04? The requirement is to use either slim or non-slim versions of Python3.10 [Bulls eye][1] image from docker hub

Comment: Can you use the `python:3.10` image without trying to reconstruct it (which your last sentence seems to imply)?  Why that specific (4-year-old) distribution?

Comment: Thank you for your quick help David, could you please elaborate little bit on how can I include that in docker file (I have less knowledge with that part). 
Upgrading the Ubuntu to latest stable release is in pipe line and it could be taken up in next 6 months.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Ubuntu 18 docker image, then install python 3.10 inside it.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get -y update && apt -get install software-properties-common \
&& add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && apt install python3.10
```

Comment: Thank you Ali for sharing the information. But, I am looking to get the images from Python docker hub and not from private or third-party repos.

Comment: apt -get has a space with needs to removed in the command above

Answer (score -4):

I am able to build the image on ubuntu 18.04 by including python3.10

**Step-1:** Write a docker file
FROM python:3.10-bullseye
RUN  mkdir WORK_REPO
RUN  cd  WORK_REPO
WORKDIR  /WORK_REPO
ADD hi.py .
CMD ["python", "-u", "hi.py"]

**Step-2:** Build the image
docker build -t image_name .

**Step-3:** Run the docker image
docker run image_name

**Step-4:** Connect to the container and check the Python version

I hope this would be helpful for someone who is completely new in writing dockerfile.

**Many Thanks,
Suresh.**

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for, which is install in ubuntu.

Comment: @Suresh given that you accepted Debian Bullseye in the base image in this answer, but the question says "in Ubuntu container", maybe it's time to change either of these for consistency's sake?

Comment: I apologize for not being more explicit while I was writing the question.